# Why do we make the distinction between $(A_1,B_2)$ and $(B_2, A_1)$ but not $(A_1,A_2)$ and $(A_2,A_1)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have the following problem:

> A pair of fair dice is tossed. Find the probability of getting a total
> of $8$

The problem seemed fairly simple until I looked at the solution after solving it.

The author did the following:

> Of the $(6)(6)=36$ elements in the sample space, only $5$ elements $(2,6), (3,5), (4,4), (5,3)$, and $(6,2)$ add to $8$. Hence the probability of obtaining a total of $8$ is $5/36$

What I don't understand is why we didn't count $(4,4)$ twice, when solving the exercise I had the same reasoning except that I counted $(4,4)$ twice since I see that $(A_1,A_1) \neq (A_2,A_1)$

Note: the solution comes from the solution manual of the book.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have a red die and a blue die, there is only one way to get $(4, 4)$, you must obtain a $4$ on both the red die and the blue die.

Comment: Toss two fair coins. There are four equally likely possible outcomes: HH, HT, TH and TT.  You do not count HH twice.  In terms of your title, you distinguish $(A_1,B_2)$ and $(A_2,B_1)$

Comment: Another way of saying much the same thing.  If you roll a pair of dice, there are 36 possible different outcomes that you can get, because $(6)^2 = 36.$  Of those $36$ outcomes, exactly $5$ of the $36$ outcomes involve having the sum of the two dice $= 8$ (you should convince yourself that this is true).

Comment: thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you'll be convinced by a simulation, but here
are results from ten million rolls of two dice--one red and one blue
as @NDTaussig suggests. With 10 million replications, probabilities approximated by simulation should be accurate to about three decimal places.

```
set.seed(2021)
n = 10^7
r = sample(1:6, n, rep=T)
table(r)/n
r
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.1665514 0.1666612 0.1667533 0.1665278 0.1666923 0.1668140 
b = sample(1:6, n, rep=T)
table(b)/n
b
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
0.1668560 0.1666602 0.1666850 0.1666860 0.1666270 0.1664858 
s = r + b
table(s)/n
s
        2         3         4         5         6         7 
0.0277760 0.0556208 0.0833264 0.1111920 0.1389286 0.1665705 
        8         9        10        11        12 
0.1388043 0.1110687 0.0833665 0.0555016 0.0278446 
mean(s == 8)
[1] 0.1388043   # aprx P(S = 8) = 5/36
5/36
[1] 0.1388889

hdr = "Distribution of Sums on Two Fair Dice"
frb = rep("wheat", 11);  frb[7]="skyblue2"
ctp=(1:12)+.5
hist(s, prob=T, br=ctp, col=frb, main=hdr)
```

[image]

Comment: you are always coming with these simulation approaches! nice to see it =)